# MVC: Send object and integer to controller as JSON

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to send a custom object and an integer to my controller action using jQuery AJAX.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetFilenameSuggestion(Document document, int tradeId)
{
    //do stuff...
}
```

In my JS, I've tried to create the json sent to the controller in several ways, including:

```
var json = JSON.stringify({ document: document, tradeId: tradeId });
//or
var json = { document: JSON.stringify(document), tradeId: tradeId };
//or
var json = { document: document, tradeId: tradeId };
```

and here's my jQuery AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "/Document/GetFilenameSuggestion",
        data: json,
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        //do bad stuff...
    },
    success: function (data) {
        //do good stuff...
});
```

Any suggestions on how to do this? I am getting an internal server error when the ajax posts, and I'm 99% sure it's due to how the arguments are being passed to the controller action.

Comment: `document.tradeId = tradeId;` and `data: document` (and remove the `contentType` option) should work

Comment: How model binding is setup for `Document` class in you MVC site?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Since I don't want to arbitrarily add a tradeId property to my Document class (it's used heavily throughout the app), I should probably just create a viewmodel that wraps both document and tradeId. I was just being lazy and thought there was an easy fix in the JS.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I'm just using whatever is the OOB model binding with MVC.

Comment: @wooters. You don't need to add a `TradeId` property to your `Document` class. The code I showed just adds it to the javascript object and if your remove the `contentType` option it will be sent as `.../GetFilenameSuggestion?tradeId=someValue&aPropertyOfDocument=someValue&anotherPropertyOfDocument=someValue&....` - the `DefaultModelBinder` will match it up correctly

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks, your suggestion worked. Please post it as the answer if you like.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Actually I ended up creating a viewmodel to wrap the object and int, because `document` contained nested objects, and the `DefaultModelBinder` didn't like that.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.stringify` to convert your javascript object to it's json string version and specify the `contentType` as "`application/json`".

The below code should work fine.

```
var model = { document: { DocumentName: "Dummy" }, tradeId: 34 };

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "/Document/GetFilenameSuggestion",
    data: JSON.stringify(model),
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        //do bad stuff...
    },
    success: function(data) {
        //do good stuff...
    }
});
```

for this action method signature

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetFilenameSuggestion(Document document, int tradeId)
{
    // to do : return some useful JSON data
}
```